# How to get the nested object values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How do I perform the filter in collection. For example I've the collection of data like this and I want to do this `rits_dbx_1>0.2,simon_dbx_1<0.5`

```
{
   "threads":{
      "threads_participants":{
         "participant":[
            {
               "@all_user_n_grams":"0",
               "@reference":"rits_dbx_2",
               "overall_user_participation":"0.0",
               "thread":{
                  "@thread_id":"5e778ea6a28f9a3881c330b4",
                  "#text":"{'relative_to_thread_interactors': 0.0, 'relative_to_self_threads': 0}"
               }
            },
            {
               "@all_user_n_grams":"11",
               "@reference":"rits_dbx_1",
               "overall_user_participation":"1.0",
               "thread":{
                  "@thread_id":"5e778ea6a28f9a3881c330b4",
                  "#text":"{'relative_to_thread_interactors': 1.0, 'relative_to_self_threads': 1.0}"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

First I tried to get the value using the find method.

```
 db.xml_collection.find({"threads.threads_participants.participant": {"@reference": "rits_dbx_2"}})
```

Also it returned nothing. Can you help with the above condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you you are trying to find

"@reference":"rits_dbx_2" and "overall_user_participation":["$gt":0.5]

or

"@reference":"simon_dbx_1" and "overall_user_participation":["$lt":0.2]

if so:

```
list(db.xml_collection.find({"$or": [{"threads.threads_participants.participant.@reference":"rits_dbx_2","threads.threads_participants.participant.overall_user_participation":{"$gt":"0.2"}},{"threads.threads_participants.participant.@reference":"simon_dbx_1","threads.threads_participants.participant.overall_user_participation":{"$lt":"0.2"}}]}))
```

I also recommend you to use float instead of string for overall_user_participation field to improve comparing performance and correctness.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I want get all the collection document that matches that condition. Let me try yours and let you know.